# Moving Project folder within solution in VSS

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I have a solution in VSS with this structure (simplified):

```
Solution1
|-Project1
|-Project2
|--Project2
|-Project3
```

You see the second Project2 folder?
Somehow it got inside that wrapping project2 folder.
How can I move painlessly all content of Project2 one level up,
so that I wont have Project2/Project2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try the steps below:

1. Backup the solution
2. Open VSS Explorer, move project2 folder
3. Open VS, go to File->Source Control->Change Source Control, update the server path of Project2
4. Save the solution.

Comment: The problem is - there is no such thing as "moving" in VSS, so step 2 cannot be performed. That's why I am asking...

Comment: You can find Move command under File menu in the VSS Explorer.